# How to remove duplicates in std::vector of user defined class?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, c++17

I have a list of Text Editors that is to be rendered on the application whenever the user selected a file. It works well however when I started to delete elements on the list to signify that they were closed by the user and not to be rendered again, the problem starts to arise when I selected that same file that was deleted earlier to have a duplicate. So, I was trying to remove the duplicates by first sorting the list and then use std::unique before rendering.

Here's the part where I render the text editors

```
if(!Opened_TextEditors.empty())
{   
   std::sort(Opened_TextEditors.begin(), Opened_TextEditors.end());
   auto last = std::unique(Opened_TextEditors.begin(), Opened_TextEditors.end());
   Opened_TextEditors.erase(last, Opened_TextEditors.end());

   auto it = Opened_TextEditors.begin();
   while(it != Opened_TextEditors.end())
   {   
        if(it->IsWindowVisible())
        {   
            it->Render();
            if(it->IsWindowFocused()){
                char buffer[255];
                selected_window_path = it->GetPath(); // determines which window is active or currently selected. For writing contents on status bar
                selected_editor_path = it->GetPath(); // This is to deterimine which window is focused or currently selected. For determining where to render the next selected window. This is to reduce reordering during rendering.
                auto cpos = it->GetCursorPosition();

                snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Ln %d, Col %-6d %6d lines  | %s | %s | %s | %s ", cpos.mLine + 1, cpos.mColumn + 1, it->GetTotalLines(),
                        it->IsOverwrite() ? "Ovr" : "Ins",
                        it->CanUndo() ? "*" : " ",
                        it->GetFileExtension().c_str(), 
                        it->GetFileName().c_str()
                 );
                 current_editor = std::string(buffer);
            }
            ++it;
        }
        else {//Bug: When the editor was deleted and is selected again to be rendered, causes some sort of anomalies where it tends not being docked and somtimes when it was rendered and tried to close any window, every window will be deleted.
             it = Opened_TextEditors.erase(it);
             }
           }
        }
```

And here's the part where I add the selected text editor

```
auto it = std::find(Opened_TextEditors.begin(), Opened_TextEditors.end(), parentNode.FullPath);
if(it == Opened_TextEditors.end())
{   
     static unsigned int id = 0;
     ArmSimPro::TextEditor editor(parentNode.FullPath, id,bg_col.GetCol());
     auto programming_lang = ArmSimPro::TextEditor::LanguageDefinition::CPlusPlus();
     ++id;
     for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ppnames) / sizeof(ppnames[0]); ++i)
           std::future<void> PreprocIdentifier = std::async(std::launch::async, SetupPreprocIdentifiers, programming_lang, ppvalues[i]);
     for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(identifiers) / sizeof(identifiers[0]); ++i)
            std::future<void> Identifiers = std::async(std::launch::async, SetupIdentifiers, programming_lang, identifiers[i], idecls[i]);
                
    editor.SetLanguageDefinition(programming_lang);

    std::ifstream t(parentNode.FullPath.c_str());
    if (t.good())
    {
        std::string str;
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        str.reserve(t.tellg());
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        editor.SetText(str);
     }

     if(!selected_editor_path.empty()){
         int index = GetTextEditorIndex(selected_editor_path) + 1;
         Opened_TextEditors.insert(Opened_TextEditors.begin() + index, editor);
     }
     if(Opened_TextEditors.empty())
         Opened_TextEditors.push_back(editor);
     }
```

When I run it, it gives an error message:

```
call to object of class type 'std::less<void>': no matching call operator found
call to object of class type 'std::less<void>': no matching call operator found
```

So, I added an function on my class that overloads the "==" operator:

```
class TextEditor
{
 public:
        .....
        bool operator==(TextEditor& other) { return this->path == other.path; }
        bool operator==(const TextEditor& other) { return this->path == other.path; }
        bool operator==(const std::string& full_path) const { return this->path == full_path; }
        .....
};
```

I don't have much of experience in `<algorithm>` since I was just starting to learn for a few months but I suspect the error was coming from `std::unique`. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638425/can-stdunique-be-used-to-determine-if-objects-of-a-custom-class-have-the-same) similar problem but still get the same error. Is there anything that I could add on my `TextEditor` class to satisfy the parameters on the `std::unique`?

At this problem I've seen people saying to use `std::set` to avoid duplicates. However, to allow adding text editors next to the current selected text editor need an ability to insert at a particular index. This is done by searching through the list and finds the editor that has the specified file path and then get its position.

Comment: Copy everything to an [unordered set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), clear the vector, and copy everything back.

Comment: Try making your operators const. `bool operator==(TextEditor& other) const { ... }` `less` is looking for `operator<` not `operator==`.

Comment: And [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into yout question. All environments have tabs where you can find the complete build-log as text, copy-paste that into your questions.

Comment: *but I suspect the error was coming from std::unique* -- `std::sort(Opened_TextEditors.begin(), Opened_TextEditors.end());` -- What is the sorting criteria here?  The 2-argument `std::sort` requires that your type can be compared using `<`.  Also, there is a lot of code you posted that is not relevant to the issue.   What type is `Opened_TextEditor`?  Just that alone would have been enough to see if `std::sort` or `std::unique` would have been successfully compiled.

Comment: `TextEditor& operator=(const TextEditor& editor) { return *this; }` -- What is the reason for writing a user-defined assignment operator?  If `TextEditor` contains members that need to be copied, you are introducing side-effects that would be a headache to debug if something goes wrong with your program due to not copying *all* of the members.

Comment: The sorting criteria for Opened_TextEditor class is to sort the elements based on the file path asigned to them,

Comment: Then you should be using the 3-argument [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) that specifies the sorting criteria as the third argument.  But again, if your assignment operator does what your code suggests, `std::sort` is going to copy items around, causing all sorts of havoc due to the file path not being copied.

Comment: Also, [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) has a 3-argument version, similar to `std::sort`, that accepts the `==` criteria instead of you having to write an overloaded version of `==` for the `TextEditor` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error more than likely is coming from `std::sort` and not `std::unique`.  The 2-argument `std::sort` requires that the type can be compared with `<`, which `TextEditor` does not have.

I would use the 3-argument `std::sort` that allows a predicate to be used, instead of having to provide an overloaded `operator <` to the `TextEditor` class.

Here is a full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class TextEditor
{
    std::string path;
    public:
        TextEditor(const char * p) : path(p) {}
        const std::string& getPath() const { return path;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<TextEditor> v;
    v.push_back("path1");
    v.push_back("path2");
    v.push_back("path1");  // Duplicate

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const TextEditor& e1, const TextEditor& e2)
    { return e1.getPath() < e2.getPath(); });

    auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const TextEditor& e1, const TextEditor& e2)
    { return e1.getPath() == e2.getPath(); });

    v.erase(it, v.end());

    for (auto& te : v)
    {
        std::cout << te.getPath() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
path1
path2
```

Note that the 3-argument `std::unique` call was made, thus not needing to write an overloaded `operator==`.